# Not getting updated cursor position in ace editor?

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

I am working on angularJs in which I am using an ace editor.

I want to get cursor position every time I change cursor position on the screen.

Problem is, I always get the initial position of the cursor, not the latest position.

Below is my code:

```
 this.editorOptions = {
       mode: 'groovy',
       theme: 'textmate',
       showGutter: true,     // Enabling line numbers for the editor
       useWrapMode: true,
       showPrintMargin: false, // Disabling print margin line from the editor
       onLoad: (editor) => {   //  Triggered when the editor gets loaded (i.e., on initial load of the editor)
        this.policyEditorBox = editor;
       },
       onChange: (editor) => {     // Triggered on content change of the editor
           this.policyEditorBox = editor[1];
           console.log("policy editor:",this.policyEditorBox);
           console.log(editor[1].selection.cursor.row); //this line always print zero (initial position)
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases change is fired before selection is updated,
try using the async `"input"` event `editor.on("input", function() {})`, or use some kind of debounce timeout to run your code after the editor is fully updated.

Comment: would love to add an extra +1 to this one.Thanks.